# How to I get WIndows 8 back?

Tags: windows, windows-8

SO yesterday I was complaining about Windows 8, and my friend told me to download Ubuntu, get a blank disk, do that stuff then he got me to just restart PC and do that(no idea what I was doing he just told me to do it and I did) now I have Ubuntu but I don't like it or understand it... and Windows 8 is now gone completely?
Is there any way I can get Windows 8 back... like how I got Ubuntu?
Please help

Comment: Unlike Ubuntu (Which is free and available to download and use anywhere), Windows isn't. You need to have a valid Licensed Windows DVD or an OEM provided recovery disk to be able to install Windows back on your PC. Instruction for installing Windows is out of scope for this site.

Comment: It's possible that you still have Windows 8 on your computer except that you only overwrote the Windows 8 bootloader, which can be repaired (it's not hard to do). So the question is *how did you install Ubuntu?*. Did you replace Windows 8 with Ubuntu or did you install Ubuntu **alongside** Windows 8 (dual boot)?

Comment: as @karel mentioned, there's a way to install windows alongside Ubuntu and dual boot (I do that most of the time). Since you didn't know what you were doing and can't describe it to us, we can't really help you out because we don't know how you did it. My best suggestion is you contact the friend and get his help in figuring it out. Besides that, I really suggest you give Ubuntu a try, it's pretty cool once you get used to it

Comment: Your computer might have a 'recovery partition' you can boot from and reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Microsoft, or a Microsoft trusted partner and they can give you a recovery disk, so you can get your Windows 8 back.

Comment: What about: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/clean-install